# Photo Gallery like table iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, gallery, tile

I am in the process of designing an application that will look like the image below. I am wondering if there is anything out there that will help me create this style of a table. I have seen three20 and other sources. I already figured out how to load images from the website I need, using JSON, now I need to put it into that view style. . It looks like it may be a basic gallery layout, but I am not sure where the best place to start may be.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/agoGx.jpg

EDIT: Thanks guys, this ended up being quite helpful as well: http://www.scott-sherwood.com/ios-6-uicollectionviewcontroller/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check `UICollectionView` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: http://www.scott-sherwood.com/ios-6-uicollectionviewcontroller/

This ended up being quite helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`UICollectionView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html). It's perfect for that sort of thing.

Ask again with specific questions if you have them.

Answer (score 0):

The new `UICollectionView` framework is made for things like this, and it's really easy to use. The only downside to using a collection view is that it's only available on iOS 6+, so if you want backwards compatibility, you might want to look into third-party open source frameworks.

Here's a great tutorial on `UICollectionView`s to help you get started.

http://www.adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial.php